# Wrap the real right around the trigonometric circle (Metapost)

Tags: metapost

I am trying to reproduce this figure but I have the impression that alpha does not correspond to the length of the path subpath (0,1.3) of p and that the value -pi/2 is not correct.

```
  \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
  \usepackage{luatex85}
  \usepackage{luamplib}
  \begin{document}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  \begin{mplibcode}

  beginfig(1);

  numeric u, pi;
  u = 10mm;
  pi = 3.141592654;

  path C, T, xx, yy;

  C = fullcircle scaled 5u;

  xx = (point 4 of C -- point 0 of C) scaled 1.1;
  yy = (point 6 of C -- point 2 of C) scaled 1.1;

  T = ((xpart point 0 of C,200) -- (xpart point 0 of C,-200));

  numeric l;
  l = length subpath(0,1.3) of C;

  draw xx;
  draw yy;
  draw C withpen pencircle scaled 3/4;
  draw origin -- (point 1.2 of C) withcolor blue;
  draw  subpath(0,1.2) of C withcolor blue;
  draw T withcolor red;

 label.urt(btex $\pi$ etex,(xpart point 0 of C,u*(pi)));
 label.urt(btex $1$ etex,(xpart point 0 of C,u*1));
 label.urt(btex $2\pi$ etex,(xpart point 0 of C,u*(2pi)));
 label.urt(btex $\frac{\pi}{2}$ etex,(xpart point 0 of C,u*(pi/2)));
 label.urt(btex $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ etex,(xpart point 0 of C,u*(-pi/2)));
 label.urt("$M$", point 1.3 of C);
 label.llft("$O$", origin);
 label.lrt("$I$", point 0 of C);
 label.ulft("$J$", point 2 of C);
 label.urt(btex $\frac{\pi}{2}$ etex, point 2 of C);

 fill fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam
 shifted (xpart point 1.2 of C, ypart point 1.2 of C)
 withcolor blue;

 endfig;
 \end{mplibcode}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for comparison (or more honestly just for my own amusement), here is another version, that you might find instructive.

[image]

### Source

Compile with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric u, pi, alpha;
    u = 42;
    pi = 3.141592653589793;
    alpha = 1.2;

    % you might not want this grid
    numeric minx, miny, maxx, maxy;
    minx = -7/2; maxx = 1; miny = -2; maxy = 13/2;
    for x=minx step 1/2 until maxx:
        draw ((x, miny) -- (x, maxy)) scaled u withcolor 3/4 white;
    endfor
    for y=miny step 1/2 until maxy:
        draw ((minx, y) -- (maxx, y)) scaled u withcolor 3/4 white;
    endfor

    path C, ii, jj;
    C = fullcircle scaled 2u shifted (-u,0);
    ii = (point 4 of C -- point 0 of C) shifted - center C scaled 1.15 shifted center C;
    jj = (point 6 of C -- point 2 of C) shifted - center C scaled 1.15 shifted center C;

    path negative_d, positive_d;
    positive_d = origin -- (0, maxy) scaled u;
    negative_d = origin -- (0, miny) scaled u;

    draw negative_d withcolor 2/3 red;
    draw positive_d withcolor 1/2 green;
    label.lft("$\cal D$", 3/2 pi * u * up) withcolor 1/2 green;

    vardef mark_y_axis(expr value, name, shade) = 
        save p; pair p; p = value * u * up;
        draw (left--right) scaled 2 shifted p withcolor shade;
        label.rt(name, p shifted 2 right);
    enddef;

    mark_y_axis(1,      "$1$",      1/2 green);
    mark_y_axis(alpha,  "$\alpha$", 1/2 green);
    mark_y_axis(1/2 pi, "$\pi/2$",  1/2 green);
    mark_y_axis(pi,     "$\pi$",    1/2 green);
    mark_y_axis(2pi,    "$2\pi$",   1/2 green);
    mark_y_axis(-1/2 pi, "$-\pi/2$",  2/3 red);

    z.M = point alpha * 4 / pi of C;

    path trajet; 
    trajet = subpath (0, alpha * 4 / pi) of C .. {left} (minx, 4/3)*u;

    numeric a; pair p;
    a = arctime pi*u of trajet;
    p = point a of trajet;
    draw (down--up) scaled 2 rotated angle direction a of trajet shifted p withcolor 1/2 green;
    label.ulft("$\pi$", p);

    draw ii withpen pencircle scaled 1/4;
    draw jj withpen pencircle scaled 1/4;
    draw C;
    draw trajet withcolor 1/2 green;

    draw center C -- z.M withcolor 1/4 blue;
    label("$M$", z.M + (-2,8)); filldraw fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam shifted z.M;

    vardef show_mapping(expr a, b) = 
        interim ahangle := 30;
        drawarrow a {left} .. b {dir 240}
            cutbefore fullcircle scaled 8 shifted a
            cutafter  fullcircle scaled 8 shifted b
            withcolor 3/4 blue;
    enddef;

    show_mapping(pi * u * up, p);
    show_mapping(alpha * u * up, z.M);

    label.llft("$O$", center C); 
    label.lrt("$I$", point 0 of C);
    label.llft("$J$", point 2 of C);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Some notes

- You can vary `u` to adjust the size of the whole thing (except the font sizes)
- But it's probably not a good idea to vary the value of the variable `pi`. There is no constant built into MP, so I just defined it here, using the value that happens to be built into my editor.  If you don't trust my constant you could try writing `pi = 1/4 arclength (quartercircle scaled 16);` which also works...
- You can just remove the grid if you don't want it
- I have put the point `alpha` and the corresponding point `M` in the mathematically correct places.  To get from the scalar value of `alpha` to the correct point round the circle I used `point alpha * 4 / pi of C`.  This is because the length of a semicircle is 4 units of MP time and pi units of length.
- You can use arbitrary suffixes with the `z` notation, so `z.M` works just like `z0`.  You need the `.` to separate the `z` from the suffix if the suffix is alphabetic.
- `arctime x of p` finds the "time" `t` along path `p` such that `length(subpath(0, t) of p) = x`, which is exactly what we want to find the point that is `pi` units along our curved path.
- the `show_mapping` definition shows a way to shorten a path using `cutbefore` and `cutafter` (and shows off nice thin arrow heads).

Comment: Thank you very much, what a mastery of this great tool ! When you write `u=42`, what is the unit of measure ?

Comment: 42 points. Postscript points are the default unit.  1 in = 2.54 cm = 72 points. In TeX terms they are `bp` rather than `pt`.  So 42pt is 7/12 in or about 1.48cm.  42 is of course always the answer. :-)

Answer (score 7):

For the labels on your `y`-axis, you use

```
label.urt(btex $\pi$ etex,(xpart point 0 of C,u*(pi)));
label.urt(btex $1$ etex,(xpart point 0 of C,u*1));
label.urt(btex $2\pi$ etex,(xpart point 0 of C,u*(2pi)));
label.urt(btex $\frac{\pi}{2}$ etex,(xpart point 0 of C,u*(pi/2)));
label.urt(btex $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ etex,(xpart point 0 of C,u*(-pi/2)));
label.urt("$M$", point 1.3 of C);`
```

First, this has a lot of repetitions which makes it hard to adjust, so let's move this into a macro:

```
vardef labeled (expr t, y) =
  save p; pair p;
  p = (xpart point 0 of C, y*u);
  label.urt(t, p);
enddef;

labeled(btex $\pi$ etex,pi);
labeled(btex $1$ etex,1);
labeled(btex $2\pi$ etex,2pi);
labeled(btex $\frac{\pi}{2}$ etex,pi/2);
labeled(btex $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ etex,-pi/2);
```

Now we can add little red lines to indicate the exact positions: Add

```
draw p shifted (-0.5mm, 0) -- p shifted (0.5mm, 0)  withcolor red;
```

to `labeled`. This gives
[image]

Now we see why -pi/2 seemed to be in a odd position and not symmetric to pi/2:
`label.urt` places the label in an **u**pper **r**igh**t** position and therefore moves all labels a bit up. We can use `label.rt` in `labeled` instead to avoid this:
[image]

Now the axis still looks odd: The drawing seems to illustrate the correspondence between the length of the circular arc and the angle in radians, so it only works if the radius of the circle is 1 unit. So we change `C = fullcircle scaled 5u;` to `C = fullcircle scaled 2u;` (The diameter should be `2u`) This make the entire diagram quite small, so we could also increase `u`. Our new figure is
[image]

Now we want to add `alpha`. First we calculate `alpha` by asking for the length of the arc (`arclength`) of the path you are interested in (I use 1.2 instead of `1.3` because that is the path you actually used in your code):

```
alpha*u = arclength subpath(0,1.2) of C;
```

Then we can add

```
labeled(btex $\alpha$ etex, alpha);
```

[image]

It turns out that this arc has a length slightly below 1, so let's use `subpath(0, 1.4)` instead to make it look a bit more like your original:
[image]

Now wwe can make everything a bit bigger and add some alignment to the labels to get:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}

beginfig(1);

numeric u, pi;
u = 20mm;
pi = 3.141592654;

path C, T, xx, yy;

C = fullcircle scaled 2u;

xx = (point 4 of C -- point 0 of C) scaled 1.1;
yy = (point 6 of C -- point 2 of C) scaled 1.1;

T = ((xpart point 0 of C,6.5u) -- (xpart point 0 of C,-2u));

alpha*u = arclength subpath(0,1.4) of C;

draw xx;
draw yy;
draw C withpen pencircle scaled 3/4;
draw origin -- (point 1.4 of C) withcolor blue;
draw subpath(0,1.4) of C withcolor blue;
draw T withcolor red;

vardef labeled (expr t, y) =
  save p; pair p;
  p = (xpart point 0 of C, y*u);
  label.rt(t, p);
  draw p shifted (-0.5mm, 0) -- p shifted (0.5mm, 0)  withcolor red;
enddef;

labeled(btex $\alpha$ etex,alpha);
labeled(btex \hbox to 1.5em{\hfill$\pi$} etex,pi);
labeled(btex \hbox to 1.5em{\hfill$1$} etex,1);
labeled(btex \hbox to 1.5em{\hfill$2\pi$} etex,2pi);
labeled(btex \hbox to 1.5em{\hfill$\frac{\pi}{2}$} etex,pi/2);
labeled(btex \hbox to 1.5em{\hfill$-\frac{\pi}{2}$} etex,-pi/2);
label.urt("$M$", point 1.4 of C);
label.llft("$O$", origin);
label.lrt("$I$", point 0 of C);
label.ulft("$J$", point 2 of C);
label.urt(btex $\frac{\pi}{2}$ etex, point 2 of C);

fill fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam
shifted point 1.4 of C
withcolor blue;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I start with Metapost and I still have a lot to learn. If I dared, because I'm short of time, how to add the trajectories of the points ?

Comment: In the macro `p = (xpart point 0 of C, u*y);`

Comment: I'm not sure which trajectories you mean. The green line continuing to the left? I'm  not even quite sure what it represents, so I also can't really tell you how to draw it.

Comment: "and add some alignment to the labels " How ?

Comment: @Fabrice Oh sorry, I forgot to add the final code. Fixed that now, but basically I aligned them by just putting them into a right aligned `\hbox` in TeX.